# Converting any number in words

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there any query or function which can convert any no into words. Likes 1001 into One thousand one etc. i am using sql server 2005.

Comment: By "any number" do you mean to include recognizing pi, 1200 3/8 being "twelve hundred and three eighths", any radix, complex and hypercomplex numbers, a range from yotta to yocto, ...?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

hi try the Below proc.... it gives the output you need....

Procedure :

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnNumberToWords(@Number as BIGINT)

    RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)

AS

BEGIN

      DECLARE @Below20 TABLE (ID int identity(0,1), Word varchar(32))

      DECLARE @Below100 TABLE (ID int identity(2,1), Word varchar(32))

      INSERT @Below20 (Word) VALUES

                        ( 'Zero'), ('One'),( 'Two' ), ( 'Three'),

                        ( 'Four' ), ( 'Five' ), ( 'Six' ), ( 'Seven' ),

                        ( 'Eight'), ( 'Nine'), ( 'Ten'), ( 'Eleven' ),

                        ( 'Twelve' ), ( 'Thirteen' ), ( 'Fourteen'),

                        ( 'Fifteen' ), ('Sixteen' ), ( 'Seventeen'),

                        ('Eighteen' ), ( 'Nineteen' )

       INSERT @Below100 VALUES ('Twenty'), ('Thirty'),('Forty'), ('Fifty'),

                               ('Sixty'), ('Seventy'), ('Eighty'), ('Ninety')

DECLARE @English varchar(1024) =

(

  SELECT Case

    WHEN @Number = 0 THEN  ''

    WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1 AND 19

      THEN (SELECT Word FROM @Below20 WHERE ID=@Number)

   WHEN @Number BETWEEN 20 AND 99  

     THEN  (SELECT Word FROM @Below100 WHERE ID=@Number/10)+ '-' +

           dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 10)

   WHEN @Number BETWEEN 100 AND 999  

     THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 100))+' Hundred '+

         dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 100)

   WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000 AND 999999  

     THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000))+' Thousand '+

         dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000) 

   WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000 AND 999999999  

     THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000000))+' Million '+

         dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000)

   WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 999999999999  

     THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000000000))+' Billion '+

         dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000000)

   WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000000000 AND 999999999999999  

     THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000000000000))+' Trillion '+

         dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000000000)

  WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000000000000 AND 999999999999999999  

     THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000000000000000))+' Quadrillion '+

         dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000000000000)

  WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000000000000000 AND 999999999999999999999  

     THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000000000000000000))+' Quintillion '+

         dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000000000000000)

        ELSE ' INVALID INPUT' END

)



SELECT @English = RTRIM(@English)

SELECT @English = RTRIM(LEFT(@English,len(@English)-1))

                 WHERE RIGHT(@English,1)='-'

RETURN (@English)

END

GO
```

**Test Queries.....**

```
SELECT NumberInEnglish=dbo.fnNumberToWords ( 18)

SELECT NumberInEnglish=dbo.fnNumberToWords ( 67)

SELECT NumberInEnglish=dbo.fnNumberToWords ( 947)

-- Nine Hundred Forty-Seven

SELECT NumberInEnglish=dbo.fnNumberToWords ( 984261)

-- Nine Hundred Eighty-Four Thousand Two Hundred Sixty-One

SELECT NumberInEnglish=dbo.fnNumberToWords ( 777999888)

/* Seven Hundred Seventy-Seven Million Nine Hundred Ninety-Nine Thousand

   Eight Hundred Eighty-Eight */

SELECT NumberInEnglish=dbo.fnNumberToWords ( 222777999888)

SELECT NumberInEnglish=dbo.fnNumberToWords ( 555222777999888)

SELECT NumberInEnglish=dbo.fnNumberToWords ( 7446744073709551616)
```

Source From : http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2008/number-to-words/

Comment: Simple and elegant answer! I'm trying to make it work for zero, though. Not so simple.

Comment: There is any solution for MYSQL please?

Comment: Looking at the time when this was posted, there must be a built-in func in MS-SQL by now?? I was actually wondering how digits after a decimal (the decimals) would be interpreted e.g. 1234,89

Comment: Does anyone have the function to do the reverse of this? IE convert a string to integer.

Comment: what if it's DECIMAL.

Answer (score 6):

you could try this it works in oracle:

```
 select to_char(to_date(:number,'j'),'jsp') from dual;
```

or see [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic794134-149-1.aspx#bm794177) for a detailed link re how to do it

Comment: +1 This is the only correct answer. No need to reinvent a bike...

Comment: @RachelGallen Art isn't the OP and it might not work for the OP or (s)he might not have tried it. Does anyone know if that actually works on SQL Server?

Comment: @Thor84no, I guess I did not think of this hoping that SQL Server would have the same funct...

Comment: @Rachel Gallen, you got the tick - my first comment about reinventing a bike refers to your query. But sadly this may not work in SQL Server... They need to catch up )))

Answer (score 2):

There is no such query. you need to create your own procedure and then you can use it.

Comment: any idea to write a short procedure as per my understanding it will be lengthy one using case etc.